# How to create a workable email with ssh

Tags: email

i have gone round google and cannot find how to create an email. I use apache and write nodejs.
I installed dovecot, postfix on centos 6. please help explain better

Comment: I am unsure about what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to setup a private email server for sending (smtp) and and receiving (imap, pop) email?

Comment: I want to set it up on my hosting. Yes.

Comment: i am having issues achieving it with postfix and i write nodejs. I noticed postfix is on lamp environment

Comment: Your question is more related to server provisioning then programming. There is no need to use ruby to configure the server to act as an smtp/imap server (Unless you want to use a provisioner like Puppet or Chef). This question belongs to the ServerFault forum.

Comment: There are many good tutorials on how to setup this, like this example: https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/setup-postfix-dovecot-mysql-ubuntu-1604/